# Is it possible to concat multiple csv files with reading using chunksize?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple CSV files which I want to concat. The files may or may not have the same columns. If columns are not the same, the data in different columns should be empty.

Example
csv file1 has this data.

```
name, age
abc,  21
dsd,  20
```

csv file2 has this data

```
height, pay
5'5,    2000
5'10,   1000
```

Now I want to merge these two. For Example, they have millions of rows and I can't read them entirely. I want output in this style

```
name, age, height, pay
abc,  21,  None,  None
dsd, 20,   None,  None
   ,       5'5,   2000
   ,       5'10,  1000
```

Note that columns have null values in them if they don't have data.
I have this code but it isn't working. Appending column names with each chunk and not adding empty columns.

```
import pandas as pd
def common_member(a, b):
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
    if (a_set & b_set):
        return True 
    else:
        return False
all_files = ["/home/shahid/work-folders/Ai-Studio-input/mixed_csv/ludwig_train.csv", "/home/shahid/work-folders/Ai-Studio-input/mixed_csv/ludwig_train (copy).csv"]
merged_columns = []
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(open(file), float_precision='round_trip', chunksize=1000)
    for chunk in df:
        stop = True
        if stop ==True:
            merged_columns+= list(chunk.columns)
            break
        stop= False
print(set(merged_columns))
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(open(file), float_precision='round_trip', chunksize=1000)
    for chunk in df:
        if list(chunk.columns) == set(merged_columns):
            chunk.to_csv("/home/shahid/work-folders/Ai-Studio-input/mixed_csv/merged.csv", mode='a', index=False)
```

Comment: Just do: `df = pd.concat([df1, df2])`.

Comment: First I need to read both files in memory which Is not possible for me. I want to do it chunk by chunk. Second there can be 50 csv files or 100. Not a possible solution.

Comment: @MayankPorwal If I could read all files in memory, then I wouldn't be asking questions here.

Comment: If the data won't fit in memory, what are you planning to do with the combined data?  Flush it to disk and start over?  If so, then the `concat` solution certainly will work for you.

Comment: You do know you can concatenate CSV files one line at a time without involving pandas at all, right?  They're just strings in text files.

Comment: @TimRoberts Answer to your first comment, I want to write csv file using df.to_csv() in append mode, it will write file on disk and not memory, the data will not actully get combined at any point before written to csv file. to answer your 2nd question, yes I can write csv file line by line but how I can handle missing data due to different columns in all files?